# Don't have sound in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound

I don't have sound even though I have got the latest updates, installed the driver for the graphics card, installed alsa mixer which there was some mute but didn't do anything. What is wrong?

Comment: What connection type do you have? What soundcard do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HDMI make sure you have the HDMI audio selected in your sound settings. I had the same issue with my Nvidia Geforce GTX 550 TI at first. Then I selected HDMI/Display port 2 and it works.